# junk characters with an Epson TM-H6000 on GNU/Linux

Tags: printer

I try to print something readable in an Epson TM-H6000 on a GNU/Linux OS, but I just got junk characters like "?" or black rectangles.

I'm using CUPS and because I didn't find my printer in the Linux fondation listing, I tried to use a driver from the epson website with an available and similar printer (I didn't find mine). I don't know if I have these junk characters because I use the wrong driver or if it is because I do it wrong...

Any idea ?

For information :

- My OS : GNU/Linux Debian Jessie 7 (stable)
- My printer : Epson TM-H6000 (Thermal Hybrid POS printer)
- The driver I tried : TM/BA Series Printer Driver for Linux (Epson website)
- How I send a print :
  `lp test.txt` or `echo "Hello" | lp`